# reactive animation value that not of the style type react native reanimated-2 (SVG props)

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2, react-native-animatable

I am working with ReactNative-reanimated-2
I want to make an animation with an SVG path at color properties

I know how to do it in style properties with `useAnimationStyle`
but how can to do that with non-style properties like SVG prpos

like that

```js
const animatedStyleColor = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
  return {
    color: interpolate(nimatedValue.value, [0, 50], ['blue', 'red'], {
      extrapolateRight: Extrapolation.CLAMP,
    }),
  };
});

<Svg width={80} height={60} viewBox="0 0 8 4">
  <AnimatedPath
    d="M0 4l4-4 4 4"
    stroke={'blue'} //here I need to animation
    strokeWidth={3.5}
    fill="none"
    fillRule="evenodd"
    strokeLinecap="round"
    strokeLinejoin="round"
  />
</Svg>
```

[My Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@yoel301/animation)

but is that not  work
how can to make that

Comment: [useAnimatedProps](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedProps/) will allow you to animate Animated component props.

Comment: I've been taking a crack at it but im unfamiliar with SVG. I've gotten color changes to work with buggy behavior but it doesnt show show on the SVG https://snack.expo.dev/VmdB-GFMz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that there's a bug/issue with useAnimatedProps that is resolved by providing an empty onPress function ([here's the issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3321)):

```js
import { Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedProps,
  useDerivedValue,
  interpolateColor,
  Extrapolation,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Svg, { Path } from 'react-native-svg';

// moved out side of component to avoid recreating AnimatedPath on re-renders
const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);

export default function AssetExample() {
  const animatedValue = useSharedValue(50);
  // keep track of current color and color animating to
  const targetColor = useSharedValue('#ad08ed');
  const currentColor = useSharedValue('#acc880');
  // interpolate between to colors
  const color = useDerivedValue(() => {
    return interpolateColor(
      animatedValue.value,
      [0, 50],
      [currentColor.value, targetColor.value]
    );
  });

  const changeColor = (newColor) => {
    targetColor.value = newColor;
    currentColor.value = color.value;
    animatedValue.value = withTiming(animatedValue.value > 0 ? 0 : 50, {
      duration: 1500,
    });
  };
  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    return {
      stroke: color.value,
      strokeWidth: interpolate(animatedValue.value, [0, 50], [1.5, 3.5]),
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onPress={() => changeColor(getRandomColor())}
        title={'Change color'}
      />
      <Svg width={100} height={100} viewBox="0 0 8 4">
        <AnimatedPath
          d="M0 4l4-4 4 4"
          strokeWidth={3.5}
          fill="none"
          fillRule="evenodd"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          animatedProps={animatedProps}
          // found out there's a bug that is resolved by having onPress
          // https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3321
          onPress={() => {}}
        />
      </Svg>
    </>
  );
}

const getRandomInt = (min = 0, max = 1) => {
  const range = max - min;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + min;
};

const getRandomColor = () => {
  const rgb = [
    getRandomInt(0, 255),
    getRandomInt(0, 255),
    getRandomInt(0, 255),
  ].map((int) => int.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'));
  return '#' + rgb.join('');
};
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/EHO-7Tzq_)

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/KFt15FSHw added random opacity to getRandomColor